# Сворачивание Expand при нажатии на его контент XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Всем привет!

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы при клике на содержимое Expand - он сворачивался?

```
            <Expander Header="First Expand">
                <ListBox>
                    <ListBox.Items>
                        <CheckBox Content="First"/>
                        <CheckBox Content="Second"/>                                    
                        <CheckBox Content="Third"/>
                    </ListBox.Items>
                </ListBox>
            </Expander>
```

Это можно сделать через привязку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переделал ToggleButton под Expander (просто забиндил Name как Header) оставив логику с разворачиванием.

```
<ToggleButton Style="{DynamicResource NewToggle}" 
                 Name="First Toggle" Click="Toggle_click">
        <ListBox>
            <ListBox.Items>
                <CheckBox Content="First"/>
                <CheckBox Content="Second"/>                                    
                <CheckBox Content="Third"/>
            </ListBox.Items>
        </ListBox>
    </ToggleButton>
```

После того как мы можем делать Click делаем в код-бехайнде:

```
private void Toggle_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource.GetType().Name == "CheckBox") 
    { 
        var myCheck= (CheckBox)e.OriginalSource;
        var MyList = (ListBox)myCheck.Parent;
        var myToogle = (ToggleButton)MyList.Parent;
        myToogle.IsChecked = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

Не самый симпатичный вариант, если кто-то знает лучше - пишите!